# How to add nonce or sha to Content Security Policy for Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-config, content-security-policy

I am attempting to implement a CSP and so far it was ok until i can across a page with a large form.

I have added a 'nonce' to 'script src' but when the form is generated it adds an automated  tag that i dont know either how to add as safe or how to generate the sha value for it.

For previous sha values it was listed in the console panel so i added them but for these automated ones it just throws the error below and nothing else to narrow it down:

***Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https: nonce-123 'sha256-123=' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.***

I checked this thread [Add nonce attribute to auto-generated WebForms script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461778/add-nonce-attribute-to-auto-generated-webforms-script) but i dont understand how he generated the sha value to add to the CSP?

How could i calculate or add a nonce to this automated script for a form?